# Why would R's tensorflow::install_tensorflow() command attempt to install python3.7 into the r-reticulate conda environment?

Tags: r, tensorflow, reticulate

Simple question:
I'm on a Macbook Pro, Big Sur, R 4.1.0, following the documentation on installing tensorflow, and the `install_tensorflow(method="conda",conda="~/opt/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/")`, after telling me that I've now got a thousand conflicts, gives me the final error message:

`Error: installation of 'python=3.7' into environment '/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate' failed [error code 1]`

Nothing in the documentation says that python 3.7 is a requirement, and as someone who is new to python, why in the world would the `install_tensorflow()` command try to install a new version of python AFTER it installs all of these required python modules?

Answer (score 1):

The install_tensorflow() function has an argument where you have to tell it the version of conda you're using... not sure why, but it worked after adding this:

`install_tensorflow(method = "conda", conda = "~/opt/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/", conda_python_version = "3.9")`